# Error while creating new web application in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, windows-server, web-application-zones

I try to creating web application in SharePoint 2013 using SharePoint Central Admin Windows server 2008 R2 enterprise. 
following error:
Specified value is not supported for the domainName parameter.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what kind SQL Server + version do you use? What kind of account do you use also? Cound you explain a little bit more your configuration? What  are log entry details? Thanks

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014, windows authentication

Comment: SQL Server is on the same machine? Same domain I guess? You use a local user or a domain user? Check your DNS service on the domain controller? Is it a virtual machine? If yes, could you access it on your local browser?

Comment: You have the correlation Id in the snip that you have posted. Can you check the ULS logs against that correlation Id and help us with what the logs are saying about this

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the domain controller is not available:

https://vadivelu7.wordpress.com/2012/08/20/configuration-wizard-fails-specified-value-is-not-supported-for-the-0-parameter/